# VB.Net Designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Long story short I made a form in VB.Net project which involves lots of icons and images.
My problem is when I build my project, and then go back to that form, suddenly errors showed up.

The errors says :

> "The type 'MyProject.MyResources.Resources' has no property named 'myicon'".

Just to be clear, it worked fine before I did the build, and it happened to every single images I have on Resource.

When I chose "Ignore and Continue" all of the images I used are gone.

I tried to googled it, some says to delete my .exe file on Application/Bin/Debug folder, which is working.

But this issue has been some kind of an annoying one, since it happens again every single time I build.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this? Or this is a fixed bug from Visual Studio 2010?

Thank you

Comment: May seem obvius, but have you tried rebooting Visual Studio?

Comment: Try deleting the obj folder as well.

Comment: Change the Target framework setting back and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You edit proect files.</br>
[Please read my other answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203786/3737410

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too.

At first, I rebooted my PC/Laptop and it went back to normal. But when i build my project, it started all over again. Then i tried this:

Project -> Project Properties -> Resources -> images to drop your png image. 
If not, then do it and see if it is there otherwise drop it.

Another solution would be:

```
Me.Button1.Image = My.Resources.Resources.myicon
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello ivanzkie, sorry for my late reply got stuck with lots of other things. But I tried your solutions and the result is still no luck. The best thing ever worked for me still do delete the .exe debug file, but it's very annoying since I have to open my project all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can get over that problem if you remove the reference to the project itself, I did that and the problem went away.