# Designer fails - My.Resources.Resources' has no property named

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a problem that the designer won't display forms. It fails with the error Designer giving a warning as follows:

[image]

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Restore from source control.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't understand what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you are missing items required to load this form in your application **Resources**.

You can access the **Resources** of a project by right-clicking the project and selecting **Properties**. Then, clicking on **Resources** from the left pane.

[image: Project Resources]

The errors you receive indicates that items required to load this form in your application which is supposed to be loaded from the **Resources** are not found. In most cases, these items can be **Images**

You may want to change the designer code or restore the items missing back to **Resources**.

**Notice**: Resources might be **Strings**, **Images**, **Icons**, **Audio**, **Files** or **Others**.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Thanks I did restore them but it didn't solved the problem, so I removed the Resources file and I replace it with another one (from a backup) and then I added the missing images and it worked, the problem that the Resources file was damaged

Comment: @SuSha I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 25):

This can happen if **your project references itself**.

Visual Studio randomly does this automatically when some **controls/forms defined in the project use other (user-)controls defined in this same project**.

You can safely **remove the self-reference** in the project's "*References*" node.

Then rebuild and the designer should reload without these errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Solved problem right away! Didn't know VS would add a self reference :-/

Comment: @c31983 Glad it helps. Yes VS sometimes does strange things. :-)

Comment: This helped tremendously! Thanks a lot!

Comment: THAT's THE FIX ! Thanks !

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem after changing the namespace of the project. After that I received the same error message and was looking in this post and none of the solutions worked for me. Now that I have found the solution, I write it here to guide other developers struggeling with the same problem.
The reason of the problem was that changing the namespace didn't change the "Default namespace".
To change the "Default namespace":

1. Right click on the project and select properties
2. On the left panel select "Application"
3. Set the correct "Default namespace".

Comment: Same.  Looks like the refactoring tool made a boo boo.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old post but people will get this error, they will find this post and they will have pulled most of their hair out by the time they see this, however, this is what i've found:

1. It's not you, it's MS. I'm using VS 2015 and i still get this!
2. I've found that it occurs when somehow the project references itself
3. It's not always visible under the references node

To resolve:

1. Do a clean
2. Delete the BIN folder
3. ON PURPOSE reference the projects output exe file
4. Compile
5. Close and Open VS
6. Check your reference node, you should see the self referenced exe with an exclamation, delete the reference
7. Do another build

I find at this point my problem is resolved and i can continue working (for that day at least)

Hope this helps people that only became bald when using MS products!

Answer (score 3):

I used project name "**xxx**".

1. Open / edit project file (**xxx**.csproj or **xxx**.vbproj)
2. Find this xml node and delete.
   `<Reference Include="xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86">
   <ExecutableExtension>.exe</ExecutableExtension>
   </Reference>`
3. Open and reBuild.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43883049). I only had to make one change for obvious reasons.  I get to keep my hair!

To resolve:

1. ON PURPOSE reference the projects
   output file, (dll or exe)
2. Do a clean
3. Delete the BIN folder
4. Compile Close and Open VS
5. Unload the project and Edit the project
6. Check your reference node,you should see the self referenced exe or ddl with an exclamation, delete the reference
7. Do another build

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be due to a namespace "overlap" where my utility project - sitting within the main (VB.NET) solution - had the same root namespace as the class library (the main project) it was referencing. (Did you get all that?)

Eg, my main project ("MainProject") specified a root namespace of `Company.Project`. and my utility project (cunningly named "UtilityProject") *also* specified a root namespace of `Company.Project`.

The error could be resolved temporarily by re-adding (in my case) the image resource source links in their properties. But once the project was closed and re-opened, *POOF!*, gone.

Because I have to reference my main project in my utility project I couldn't just follow the advice elsewhere here and remove the reference. So I tried changing the root namespace of the utility project to `Company`, corrected some resulting form designer reference errors and Bob was once again my uncle.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, when I did change the namespace. So what I did was:

1. I changed the namespace by selecting it and renaming it
2. I clicked on the light bulb and renamed all the references
3. Removed all the projects from the solution
4. Closed the Visual Studio
5. Renamed all the projects in windows explorer
6. Opened Visual Studio  and added all the projects again

The above steps I did to change namespace, but when I opened windows form I got the same errors like here on the first screen you had. 
To fix that I noticed that I have to go to properties of each project I had and renamed the namespace there as well. When I did this, this error was solved and everything was working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution... I renamed a project and VS did the mass rename... except for the damn .exe.  Updated the project properties for *newname*.exe and all's good

Answer (score 0):

The first time this problem happened, we tried some of the solutions listed here, some version of [Richard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43883049) and [Greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348671/12291500), which worked to solve the problem. But when it reoccurred the next day, that didn't work. Neither did uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (we're using Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.2.5).

We looked for further suggestions. On Stack Overflow on the issue of this designer error of there's this current question with its suggestions for referencing the exe, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70903285/12291500). Someone asked DevExpress [this question](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T711301/designer-error-the-type-xxx-resources-has-no-property-named-yyy) on their support site. There's a few others scattered around the internet, but they all seem to have the same answers on them as this question has (perhaps even copied and pasted, but who knows).

What ended up solving the problem was deleting the Visual Studio cache, as suggested [by Reza in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903285/the-type-properties-resources-has-no-property-named#comment129630160_70903285). Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673091/12291500), we opened `appdata` to look for the cache. This can be done by pressing `WindowsKey + R` to open the `Run` dialog box, typing in `%appdata%` and pressing `Enter`. We found the cache files in `appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`, and deleted everything out of there. (Make sure VS is closed when you try to do this, otherwise it will say "Unable to Delete" because the files are in use.) When we opened VS, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted all the design code before realizing how to fix the issue. You should follow these steps :

1. On Your References Node On The Solution Explorer Click On It
2. You Will Find That Your Current Project Is Named On Childs Of This
   Node (The Items Under It If You Expand References) Right Click And
   Delete
3. Right Click On Your Project And Clean

[image: In This Items You Will Your Current Project Here Just Delete It , Mine Was DVLDUILAYER]