# Where is the Visual Studio 2017 Winforms Designer cache?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I'm getting some annoying errors from Visual Studio Designer when trying to open one of my forms (Could not load type x from assembly y, even though assembly y clearly contains type x; the project builds and runs fine). It looks like Visual Studio Designer cache issue to me. I looked around and it seems like Visual Studio Designer uses a ShadowCache, normally found at

> C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_6d397e1a\Designer\ShadowCache

However, that folder is empty. This suggests to me that there must be some other cache location, since I am using designer for some other things, there should at least be something in the designer cache location...

Answer (score 5):

To clean windows forms designer project assemblies, you need to delete subforlders of `ProjectAssemblies` folder which is located in `%userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\` under one of the folders depending to your visual studio version and edition.

For example for me:

```
%userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_a26f780e\ProjectAssemblies
```

If you look in the folder, you see subfolders containing assemblies of your projects.