# The latencies to process the user events increase with time in a GUI application running on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, latency

Everybody,

Context:
Application coded in C#, GUI controls from WinForms and DevExpress, runs on Windows 10, 64 bits, 32 GB.
of memory, Intel i7.

When I run my application for roughly 8 hours, its latency regarding user events becomes slower. I noticed that:

1- The number of GDI objects remains practically the same (202 down to 196)
2- The number of USER objects increases by a factor 10 (400 to 4000)
3- The free physical memory on my computer did not change much (16.3 down 16.1 GB.)

When the application runs, other applications are open but I don't use/interact with them.

I don't understand how the number of USER objects (bullet #2) can increase a lot but the free physical memory remains roughly the same.

But ultimately, I am looking for the cause of the increased latencies.
Can you suggest hypothesis, how to collect more meaningful clues, or better, an explanation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using something like `[Controls].Clear()` somewhere?

Comment: Since I wrote the question, I noticed a warning saying the Garbage Collector is under pressure. Since the latencies increase with time, can the pressure on the GC increase with time? I guess yes.

All in all it points into this direction. I need to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

Try that: ( Maybe that optimization your app in next load) - after first time

```
        ProfileOptimization.SetProfileRoot(@"C:MyAppFolder");
        ProfileOptimization.StartProfile("Startup.Profile");
```

**You can apply that also for WinForms :-**

1. If you have lamda-expression events. Try to do it but with local functions and unsubscribe events again before Dispose the Form. `button1.Click += lamda method; button1.Click -= lamda method`
2. when open dialogs enclose them in using. (In WinForms Dialogs never disposed) untill you Dispose them manually.  `using(MyForm frm = new MyForm()) frm.ShowDialog();`
3. Try clean Visual Studio cache and [WinForms designer cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673091/where-is-the-visual-studio-2017-winforms-designer-cache).
4. Reset visual studio settings Tools -> Import and Export Settings : [Screenshot for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoLct.png).
5. Clean your temp and %temp% (Sometimes nuget packages use %temp% and cached it on there). Also clean prefetch folder via use Run -> Prefetch.
6. Maybe re-install DevExpress components? why not?
7. Maybe re-install Visual Studio itself? why not?
8. Make sure you usually deploy in Release mode without PDB files. Usually Debug mode are heavy as it contains pdb, debuggable things.
9. **Destroy your PC** if none of the above worked for you ;)

Edit: I think 100% you have memory leaks in your project! Some resources are not disposed maybe you define some heavy static class with GUI things. Or You don't Close() some forms or not unsubscribe their events that lead to not make GC dispose them.

**Final thought:**

1. Use `GC.Collect()` each 1 hour maybe... as bottleneck till you find where leaks happened.
2. WinForms itself leaked when you run application for a long time! That's maybe a behaviour of it. But you can at least make that leaks very slowly. or can made it very fast!. You can restart your application when (end-user) in idle mode. (If he not open any screens, forms, etc). restart his app automatically and give him same permissions and config he was on it.
3. Enclose your Dialogs in using statement. Make sure File streams Disposed (using statement). Make sure you dispose everything that are you make sure you will never use it again in your form, main form.
4. You can Force DirectX in DevExpress. Maybe it will be friendly....
5. If none of anything above worked. send Support ticket to DevExpress team and upload your project to them.