# The type 'Properties.Resources' has no property named

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I'm getting the following error on all forms that contain images (in the application's resources) when I try to open any form in the designer

```
The type 'MyApp.Properties.Resources' has no property named 'BackArrow'.
```

All images are available when I view them in the application's `Properties/Resources` tab. All images have their `Persistance` property set to `Embedded in resx`. I've cleaned, rebuilt, manually deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders many times. But this error isn't going away. Any idea why this is happening and how I can solve this problem?

**EDIT**

The call stack is:

> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyReferenceExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)

Comment: You could check what's in the Resources.Designer.cs file. Is the property present there?

Comment: Obscure problem, that works just fine when I try it in 17.0.5.  Take a look at the auto-generated Properties/Resources.Designer.cs file and verify that the properties match the resources, that the namespace name is correct and matches the corresponding line of code in the form's InitializeComponent() method and that adding a resource properly adds a new property.

Comment: @HansPassant Everything is fine with designer file. I can go to my form's designer file, right-click on the property and go to the correct property. I can also compile and run the app successfully. The images are shown as expected.

Comment: May be a silly question, but is `MyApp` the right namespace?

Comment: @PoulBak Yes. I renamed it for privacy reasons.

Comment: You may want to clean the VS designer cached files. Close VS, delete bin/obj, then clean [VS designer cache files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724628/3110834).

Comment: You may also want to make sure if the project resource file Custom Tool is correct. Click on the resx file, right click and choose properties, see the Custom Tool, it should be `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. Or you can open the resx in designer, in the dropdown on top, choose Public resource generation. You can also open Resources.cs file (which is under the resx), and see if there's a public property defined there for BackArrow.